# How to debug EventHubTrigger locally?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to debug an Azure Function locally. It's an EventHubTrigger.

**The problem is that I need to debug the code locally because I still don't have the "real" settings.**

My code currently looks like this:

```
public static class Notificator
{
    [FunctionName("Notificator")]
    public static async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("achievements")]UserAchivementNofication notification, ILogger log)
    {
    }
}
```

But when I try to debug it, I'm getting this error:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method
> 'Notificator.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus: No event hub
> receiver named achievements.

And it's normal, because it doesn't exist.

My local.settings.json is like this:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
    }
}
```

How can I debug my code?

Comment: Create a test Event Hub and send some sample events there?

Comment: How do I create a test EventHub? I'm using Azure Storage Explorer and I only see Queues, Tables and Blobs :(

Comment: Event Hubs are not part of Storage. Just make a new one via portal. "Test" is more about intended usage, otherwise it's just a normal Event Hub,

Comment: I cannot create it in the Azure Portal because I don't have access to the final Event Hub yet and I don't own any subscription myself :(

Comment: You could refer to this [article](https://nascent.blog/2017/05/22/azure-functions-event-hub-local/) about Testing Azure Function with Event Hub Trigger Locally.

Comment: Event Hub is not the best service to test locally - without access to any kind of test service, you will struggle to test your solution. If you do not have access to a subscription, you can create one for free.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68122651/294657) answer for a fully local approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an EventHub on Azure so that you can test the EventHug trigger locally,

1. Goto local.settings.json to add some settings:

> ```
> {
>   "IsEncrypted": false,
>   "Values": {
>      "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
>      "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
>      "EventHubConnectionString": "YourEventHubConnectionString"
>   }
> }
> ```

2. Your function should be like this:

   ```
   public static void Run([EventHubTrigger("EventHubName", Connection = "EventHubConnectionString")]EventData myEventHubMessage, TraceWriter log)
   ```