# How to locally develop EventHub Triggered Functions in Python (programming model v2)?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, event-handling, emulation

I would like to learn to develop Azure Functions locally using Visual Studio Code. While there are [numerous examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python?pivots=python-mode-decorators) and [demos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KARieaWBxuk&t=1200s) available for using an HTTP trigger, I'm struggling to find much information on creating a minimal working example for [event-triggered functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-python). I've even come across some [disagreements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63846854/is-it-possible-to-execute-event-hub-triggered-azure-functions-locally-without-us) regarding whether it's possible to develop locally without connecting to an actual Event Hub Service.

I have a few questions for the community:

1. Is it feasible to develop event-triggered functions locally (and with a reasonable effort)?
2. If anyone has successfully done this, could you please provide an example? I've gone through several posts, but I'm having trouble putting everything together. I saw a mention of "Thunder Client", but I'm unfamiliar with it. Could someone explain if it's an option and how it works?
3. What should the host.json and local.settings.json files look like?

I would like to start with the sample test code provided by Microsoft. Here is the code:

```
import azure.functions as func
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.function_name(name="EventHubTrigger")
@app.event_hub_message_trigger(arg_name="hub", 
                               event_hub_name="<EVENT_HUB_NAME>",
                               connection="<CONNECTION_SETTING>") 

def test_function(myhub: func.EventHubEvent):
    logging.info('Python EventHub trigger processed an event: %s',
                myhub.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
```

I appreciate any guidance or assistance you can provide. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is it feasible to develop event-triggered functions locally (and with a reasonable effort)?

Yes, Its feasible and easy to run Azure Event Hub trigger function locally and also if you deploy the same function in Function app Portal.

> 2. If anyone has successfully done this, could you please provide an example? I’ve gone through several posts, but I’m having trouble putting everything together. I saw a mention of “Thunder Client”, but I’m unfamiliar with it. Could someone explain if it’s an option and how it works?

Azure Event Hub trigger as the name suggests will trigger after your Event hub receives an Event.

My Azure Event Hub trigger function ran successfully, Locally refer below:-

[image]

[image]

> ***Steps to create Event Hub function and send events in Event Hub, You can also refer this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?pivots=programming-language-python&tabs=python-v2,in-process,functionsv2,extensionv5):-***

Create a new Function trigger with Azure Event Hub Trigger like below in your VS Code, Make sure you have Azure Function extension installed:-

I opened one Folder in my Vs Code and creates a new Function trigger like below:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now create a **local.settings.json** like below:-

[image]

Select Create new local app setting and Select your Eventhubnamespace like below:-

Select your EventhubNamespace like below:-

[image]

Select eventhub like below:-

[image]

[image]

Select consumer group as Default:-

[image]

Event Hub trigger got created successfully:-

[image]

Now, Open a new Folder in your VS Code in another terminal and add the below code to send the Events.

I have referred the below code from this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-python-get-started-send?tabs=connection-string,roles-azure-portal) but I have added a below code to send the data as a JSON instead of string as Azure event Hub trigger only triggers when JSON based data is passed in Event hub:-

**[eventsender.py](http://eventsender.py)**

> ```py
> import  json
>
>   
>
> from  azure.eventhub  import  EventData
>
> from  azure.eventhub.aio  import  EventHubProducerClient
>
>   
>
> EVENT_HUB_CONNECTION_STR = "eventhubconnectionstring"
>
> EVENT_HUB_NAME = "siliconeventhub"<eventhub name not event hub
> namespace>
>
>   
>
> async  def  run():
>
> # Create a producer client to send messages to the event hub.
>
> # Specify a connection string to your event hubs namespace and
>
> # the event hub name.
>
> producer = EventHubProducerClient.from_connection_string(
>
> conn_str=EVENT_HUB_CONNECTION_STR, eventhub_name=EVENT_HUB_NAME
>
> )
>
> async  with  producer:
>
> # Create a batch.
>
> event_data_batch = await  producer.create_batch()
>
>   
>
> # Add events to the batch.
>
> event_data_batch.add(EventData(json.dumps({"message": "First
> event"})))
>
> event_data_batch.add(EventData(json.dumps({"message": "Second
> event"})))
>
> event_data_batch.add(EventData(json.dumps({"message": "Third
> event"})))
>
>   
>
> # Send the batch of events to the event hub.
>
> await  producer.send_batch(event_data_batch)
>
>   
>
> asyncio.run(run())
> ```

Run your Event Hub trigger like below:-

Click fn + f5 or Click on run > Debug > It will prompt you to connect to a storage account like below:-

[image]

Select the storage account like below:-

[image]

Event Hub trigger Function ran successfully like below:-

[image]

Run the **[eventsender.py](http://eventsender.py)** code in another tab like below:-

[image]

My Function triggered successfully like below:-

[image]

> **My event hub namespace [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-create):-**

[image]

> **Connection String reference [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-python-get-started-send?tabs=connection-string,roles-azure-portal) :-**
>
> [image]

**My eventhub with Default consumer group:-**

[image]

**UPDATED Programming Model V2:-**

Yes, I am referring to Azure Event hub Trigger.
***I created one Azure Event Hub trigger with Python programming model v2 like below:-***

[image]

[image]

***I tried setting `UseDevelopmentStorage:true` value in `local.settings.json` but it asked me to connect to Storage account when I ran it as I did not have Azure storage emulator and azurite extension installed, In order to run your function code with UseDevelopmentStorage:true install Azurite extension and install Azure Storage emulator from this [Link](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=717179) and start it in your VS code and your function will run without a need to connect to storage account, even if it asks you to connect to storage account you can click on Debug anyway.***

**Refer below:-**

**local.settings.json:-**

```json
{

"IsEncrypted": false,

"Values": {

"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",

"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",

"AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",

"connection":"Endpoint=sb://siliconeventhub.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=zSxxxxNOrjxxxxxxxx/bnxxxxI4d1gQ="

}

}
```

[image]

**Install Azurite Extension in your VS Code for `UseDevelopmentStorage=true` to work like below:-**

[image]

**My host.json:-**

```json
{

"version": "2.0",

"logging": {

"applicationInsights": {

"samplingSettings": {

"isEnabled": true,

"excludedTypes": "Request"

}

}

},

"extensionBundle": {

"id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",

"version": "[3.15.0, 4.0.0)"

}

}
```

[image]

**My functionapp.py code referred from this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?pivots=programming-language-python&tabs=python-v2,in-process,functionsv2,extensionv5#configuration):-**

```py
import logging
import azure.functions as func

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.function_name(name="EventHubTrigger1")
@app.event_hub_message_trigger(arg_name="myhub", 
                               event_hub_name="siliconeventhub",
                               connection="connection") 
def test_function(myhub: func.EventHubEvent):
    logging.info('Python EventHub trigger processed an event: %s',
                myhub.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
```

***I have added connection="connection" which retrieves value from local.settings.json.***

Now, I run the Function and Event Hub triggered successfully with local Azure storage emulator and settings `"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"` Refer below:-

Click Fn + F5 or Run > Start Debugging to run your V2 Function  or click on Debug anyway when this pop up come as we are already using Azurite and Azure Storage emulator

[image]

> Note- In order to resolve above warning, If you have your Azure storage emulator started with the steps below it won't give you debug anyway warning like above.

Now, I started my Azure Storage emulator by searching it in start menu like below:-

[image]

Azure storage emulator started like below:-

[image]

***Azure Event hub triggered successfully like below with v2 programming model.***

[image]

Comment: Hi @SiddheshDesai, thank you for your reply. For now I have three questions: 1.) Sometimes you mentioned `Event Grid Trigger` and then you also mention `Event Hub Trigger` ? They are two different services. Although in your code I see you are referencing the  `Event Hub Trigger` , which I was asking about. 2.) As question mentions, I am not sure how to configure this in v2 programming model. Do you know what `host.json` schould look like ? 3.) Let's say I do not have an eventhub service, can I use `UseDevelopmentStorage=true` for the `AzureWebJobsStorage` parameter ?

Comment: @DataBach 1) Sorry for the confusion, I am referring to Azure Event Hub Trigger. 2) To create Azure event hub trigger with v2 programming refer this images- https://i.imgur.com/HNKmLlf.png https://i.imgur.com/kQD8mhz.png My host.json - https://i.imgur.com/nfZZDGN.png 3) Yes if you keep UseDevelopmentStorage=true setting in your local.settings.json like here- https://i.imgur.com/D74D38k.png you need to install Azurite extension in your VS Code like here - https://i.imgur.com/maXdSjp.png and the function can be ran with local emulator and run the function with debug anyway.

Comment: @DataBach Check my updated answer with section UPDATED Programming Model V2:- where I have answered all your 3 questions above and created azure event hub trigger with programming model v2 with UseDevelopmentStorage=true settings

Comment: Hi  SiddheshDesai, I have to apologize for not awarding you the bounty. I did it the first time and did not know how it works properly. I did not have time to check and so it expired. I closed the question and upvoted your answer. Again apologies and thank you for your support

Comment: @SiddheshDesai when I created functionApp via azureportal, I wasn't asked for eventhub details(namespace, name, policy) since its ideally not needed for azurefunction's existence in 1st place. But what I see now, when we create a function via VScode it does ask for the 3 extra EventHub inputs(namespace, name, policy) - Can't we skip them? Reason - I want to consume events from other team's pre-built EventHub for which they shared a connection string with me. Can I create my Java/NodeJS azurefunction via VSCode without creating my own eventhub mess but instead consume events frm other eventhub?

Comment: I have the option at my disposal to populate events in the other team's eventhub via a jenkins job they created which I need to just build with certain params. SO sicne I have this I don't want to create eventhub but rather use clients pre-built eventhub of lower env & proceed ahead instead. But I see there's no way to skip that via VSCode - any other better way to deal with this? Because I already exercised the azure portal way to create function & it does not create pacakge.json or anything basic - I had to manually add it for my javascript eventhub trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides information on how to configure development environments using VSCode, Command Prompt/Terminal, Visual Studio, and Maven to develop Azure Functions.

In their documentation they mention [Azure Functions extension for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-azurefunctions) and  [Azure Functions Core Tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-functions-core-tools) for VS Code and Command Prompt/Terminal use respectively. Visual Studio is noted as having Azure Functions included.

[Azure Functions Python developer guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?pivots=python-mode-decorators&tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level) goes in detail on how to utilize these tools and how to develop for the Azure Functions platform.

Comment: I am aware about Azure documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To this date 22/03/2023 there is no Event Hub emulator. This has several disadvantages, like that we can not unit test Azure Function code without creating and connecting to an actual Eventhub namespace. However for CICD pipelines we would like to stay independent.

@SiddheshDesai describes on how to do develop locally. This approach can still be used if emulation is not needed. If you do need the emulator and come across this post, please give an upvote to the [emulator](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/86c37ae9-7526-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c) feature on the "Share Your Ideas" board of Microsoft.